# Mobx React Form - How to implement Custom onSubmit

Tags: forms, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am using mobx-react-from and i have a a problem to figure how i can use an action that i have in my store inside obSubmit hook ....

the mobx form is working ok .. i can see the inputs and the validation 
and when i submit the form all i want is to use an action from store ...

my AutStore file :

```
import {observable,action} from 'mobx';

class AuthStore {

  constructor(store) {
      this.store = store
   }

  @action authLogin=(form)=>{

    this.store.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword().then(()=>{

    }).catch(()=>{

    })
  }

 }

 export default AuthStore
```

my AuthForm File :

```
 import {observable, action} from 'mobx';
 import MobxReactForm from 'mobx-react-form';
 import {formFields,formValidation} from './formSettings';

 const fields = [
   formFields.email,
   formFields.password
 ];
 const hooks = {

  onSuccess(form) {
     // Here i want to use an action  - authLogin from my AuthStore
     console.log('Form Values!', form.values());
  },
  onError(form) {
    console.log('All form errors', form.errors());
   }
 };

const AuthForm = new MobxReactForm({fields}, {plugins:formValidation, 
hooks});
export default AuthForm
```

i would like to know how can i connect all together thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `mobx-react-form` before but have used `mobx` and `react` extensively. There's a couple ways to do this. The way I have done it is as follows, assuming Webpack & ES6 & React 14 here. Instantiate the store, and use a `Provider` around the component that hosts the form.

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react'
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import AuthStore from '{your auth store rel path}'
import FormComponent from '{your form component rel path}'
// instantiate store
const myAuthStore = new AuthStore()
// i don't think the constructor for AuthStore needs a store arg.
export default class SingleFormApplication extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={myAuthStore} >
          <FormComponent />
        </Provider>
      )
    }
}
```

Your `FormComponent` class will need to take advantage of both the `observer` and `inject` methods of the `mobx-react` package that will wrap it in a higher order component that both injects the store object as a prop and registers a listener on the store for changes that will rerender the component. I typically use the annotation syntax and it looks like this.

```
@inject('{name of provider store prop to inject}') @observer
export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = this.props.store
  }
}
```

Finally, with the store injected, you can now pass an action from the store into an `AuthForm` method, which I would advise you modify accordingly. Have the `AuthForm` file export a method that takes an `onSuccess` method as an arg and returns the `mobx-react-form` object. I would also modify your store action to simply take the email and password as an arg instead of the whole form. In the `FormComponent` try this:

```
import { formWithSuccessAction } from '{rel path to auth form}'
```

then in constructor after `this.store = this.props.store` assignment...

```
this.form = formWithSuccessAction(this.store.authLogin)
```

then in your render method of the `FormComponent` use the `this.form` class variable to render a form as you would in the `mobx-react-form` docs.

To be as clear as possible, the `AuthForm.formWithSuccessAction` method should look something like this:

```
const formWithSuccessAction = (storeSuccessAction) => {
 const fields = [
   formFields.email,
   formFields.password
 ];
 const hooks = {

  onSuccess(form) {
     // Here i want to use an action  - authLogin from my AuthStore
     console.log('Form Values!', form.values());
     // get email and password in separate vars or not, up to you
     storeSuccessAction(email, password)
  },
  onError(form) {
    console.log('All form errors', form.errors());
   }
 };

  const AuthForm = new MobxReactForm({fields}, {plugins:formValidation, 
hooks});

  return AuthForm
}
```

Hopefully this helps you on your way.